# List all process group from root canvas

Tags: python, apache-nifi, nipyapi

- Nipyapi version: latest version
- NiFi version: 1.9
- NiFi-Registry version: None
- Python version: 2.7
- Operating System: ubuntu

#### Description

I want to get all process group but just from the root canvas, when I call `canvas.list_all_process_group(pg_id)` I got all pg from all nifi. I am asking if there is any solution to get just from root canvas.

#### What I Did

`playground_pg=canvas.list_all_process_groups(pg_id=root_pg.id)`

Answer (score 0):

There are `canvas.get_process_group` and `canvas.get_process_group_status` function, do either of those return what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You want nipyapi.nifi.ProcessGroupsApi().get_process_groups(pg_id), which only returns the Process Groups from the target, and not from all descendants.
The canvas.list_all_process_group(pg_id) is designed to get everything everywhere quickly.